# How to deal with sample size and replicates

Tags: statistics

I need to perform several replicates of an experiment, say I have 3 treatments and 4 replicates. After performing the calculation of the sample size, I get n = 100 samples needed. This means that for each replicate I need 100 samples or can I split the samples among my replicates (i.e., 25 samples per replicate)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if you want to draw conclusions about a *population*, we use *representative samples* which are adequately *sized* (sample size) and reflects all the features of the population. If calculations say that the *sample size* should be 100, we need 100 data points to make statistical arguments about the population based on these 100 data points (sample size).

You mentioned there are **4** replicates i.e. you counted 4 *separate* setups and so, if you divide 100 into 4 groups, each with 25 data points, you have, statistically, only **1** replicate with 100 datapoints, *not* 4.

Please don't forget to bring with you a pinch of salt.

Furthermore, in statistics, a rule of thumb is *more the merrier*.  In short if you ever get confused in situations like this, choose 100, not 25, in a manner of speaking. Of course your supervisor will wonder why his reagents don't last as long as it used to.